# Roslyn - Find all symbols

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm using the following code to retrieve all symbols that are used in a block of code. This includes declarations and references to symbols.
Unfortunately the GetSymbolInfo call is quite slow, and because of that the total time that this method takes can be long. Is there a way to speed this up?

```
    public static IEnumerable<ISymbol> GetAllSymbols(CSharpCompilation compilation, SyntaxNode root)
    {
        var noDuplicates = new HashSet<ISymbol>();

        var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(root.SyntaxTree);

        foreach (var node in root.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
        {
            ISymbol symbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(node) ??
                model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol;

            if (symbol != null)
            {
                if (noDuplicates.Add(symbol))
                    yield return symbol; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes. You are calling GetSymbolInfo for every node, but I doubt that you need that. For example, when you have a using declaration such as `using System.Collections.Generic;`, do you really need the symbol for the System and System.Collections namespaces? So start thinking about what symbols you need.

Answer (score 7):

I see several issues with your code.

The first one is a bit of a detail, but you say you are looking for symbols you "use". Do you consider *declaring* a symbol a kind of *using* a symbol? If not, you can get rid of `model.GetDeclaredSymbol(node)`.

The second issue is much more important: you are getting the same symbols way too often.

Take for example the following statement:

```
SomeMethod();
```

That is an `ExpressionStatement` node, withing it there is an `InvocationExpression` and in there there is an `IdentifierName`. You are calling `model.GetSymbolInfo(node)` on all three of these nodes. You should look for a way to avoid that.

You would get a lot symbols if you only called `model.GetSymbolInfo(node)` on nodes of type `SimpleNameSyntax` (or its descendents, `IdentifierNameSyntax` and `GenericNameSyntax`).

Something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<ISymbol> GetAllSymbols(CSharpCompilation compilation, SyntaxNode root)
{
    var noDuplicates = new HashSet<ISymbol>();

    var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(root.SyntaxTree);

    foreach (var node in root.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
    {
        switch (node.Kind())
        {
            case SyntaxKind.IdentifierName:
            case SyntaxKind.GenericName:
                ISymbol symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol;

                if (symbol != null && noDuplicates.Add(symbol))
                {
                    yield return symbol;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It would not get *all* symbols though. For example, symbols for operators would not be found.

And that brings me to my third point: you really should consider which symbols you are after. Do you really need *all* symbols?

Even if the answer to that is "yes", you could avoid many cases of redundant lookups, by turning the above logic around.

For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<ISymbol> GetAllSymbols(CSharpCompilation compilation, SyntaxNode root)
{
    var noDuplicates = new HashSet<ISymbol>();

    var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(root.SyntaxTree);

    foreach (var node in root.DescendantNodesAndSelf())
    {
        switch (node.Kind())
        {
            case SyntaxKind.ExpressionStatement:
            case SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression:
                break;
            default:
                ISymbol symbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol;

                if (symbol != null)
                {
                    if (noDuplicates.Add(symbol))
                        yield return symbol;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In this cased I filtered out only the `ExpressionStatement` and `InvocationExpression` from the example above. There are many more you could safely filter out, but I leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. I have a similar need to query all symbols, but I only need to query all "external" symbols (i.e. symbols the current compilation unit uses but is not defined in current unit, such as framework classes, or classes / namespaces from 3rd party assemblies), can you briefly illustrate how I should achive that?

Comment: @WeipengL Use something along the lines of `!symbol.ContainingAssembly.Equals(context.Compilation.Assembly)`

Comment: Thanks again Kris